# Grails app only use maven to run, drop support for grails

Tags: maven, grails

I have a grails application with maven enabled. Application is running fine using both:

```
grails run-app
```

and

```
mvn grails:run-app
```

Now my requirement is to run application using maven only and if application is executed using grails run-app a message is displayed to run the application using maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [Grails Disable run-app command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788000/grails-disable-run-app-command/16852404#16852404). I was also facing the same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible in grails, but you can work it around by setting a system property using maven and then in BootStrap check if this property is set (System.getProperty('NAME')) - if not, it means that app was not run by maven and you can display a message and throw Exception in order to stop grails

Comment: Nice and simple answer. @user1690588, have a look at the Maven Properties plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html

Comment: You should probably make that check `if(grailsApplication.isWarDeployed() || System.getProperty(...))` as a deployed WAR won't have the maven property set.

Comment: I wonder why would you do that? do enforce developers in your company to run using maven only? A property is an option, but a developer can set the property manually if he'd want to...not sure what you're trying to achieve