# Grails Disable run-app command

Tags: grails, maven-3, grails-plugin, grails-config

In our project there is a requirement like force all user to use mvn for running the grails application. So I have a task assigned for it like disable the run-app support or override run-app command so when other guy try to run application using grails runApp it will show some message and should exit. Can any body help please.

Comment: duplicate ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774820/grails-app-only-use-maven-to-run-drop-support-for-grails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI I resolved it by doing following step:

I created _Events.groovy by executing "grails create-script _Events". By doing this it will create _Events.groovy in scripts directory and in eventCompileStart I have written following code and it works fine for me.

```
eventCompileStart = {
if( BuildSettingsHolder.settings.grailsHome){
  println"""
              *********************************************************
              *        "grails run-app" support is disabled           *
              *                                                       *
              *       Try to run "mvn clean grails:run-app"           *
              *                                                       *
              *********************************************************
     """
    System.exit(0)
}
```

}

I hope it will help some one.